# reset listview after filtering

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

I am using a AutoCompleteTextView (will later be changing this to an editText but one problem at a time) to filter the results of my listView implementing a textWatcher:

```
fqp = new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                String itemName = constraint.toString();
                return getSearch(itemName);
            }
        };

Cursor getSearch(String itemName) {
        String searchSelect = "(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE ? )";
        String[]  selectArgs = { "%" + itemName + "%"};
        Cursor searchCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                queryUri,
                projection,
                searchSelect,
                selectArgs,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
        );
        return searchCursor;
    }

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        String empty = "";
        if(s.toString() == empty){
            adapter.changeCursor(getAll());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

This filter works just fine, but i need to figure out a way to reset my list once my autoCompleteTextView is empty. Surely there is a correct way to do this other than testing if it's empty but that's what i tried to no avail. Also should i just create two Cursors: one containing my full list and the other my filtered list so i don't have to re-query the content provider?

Comment: `s.toString() == empty`. no. Use either `equals`, or `TextUtils.isEmpty(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to lie in this line

```
if(s.toString() == empty)
```

In Java, you cannot compare Strings like this, you need to use

```
if(s.toString().equals(empty))
```

Also TextWatcher is not getting called because the listener is not linked to your AutoCompleteTextView.

---

*Also should i just create two Cursors: one containing my full list and the other my filtered list so i don't have to re-query the content provider?*

If the filtered list will have the same data every time, then yes it's better to keep a reference to it instead of doing a new query.

Example using EditText:

```
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(fqp);
search.addTextChangedListener(watch);

fqp = new FilterQueryProvider() {
    @Override
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        String itemName = constraint.toString();
        return getSearch(itemName);
    }
};

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    queryUri,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE+" ASC"
);

Cursor getSearch(String itemName) {
    String searchSelect = "(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE ? )";
    String[]  selectArgs = { "%" + itemName + "%"};
    Cursor searchCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        queryUri,
        projection,
        searchSelect,
        selectArgs,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"
    );
    return searchCursor;
}

TextWatcher watch = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        String empty = "";
        if (s.toString().equals(empty)) {
            adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i thought about that after posting and tried it out but it's still not working. Also i thought it might be because textwatcher only calls onTextChanged after a certain number of characters is entered. So i tried to test if the input is four spaces then reset but it is still not working. It seems to me that there should be a method in text watcher that knows when i delete my input or change focus. Surely there is a better way to implement this?

Comment: Is onTextChanged even called? Did you set it as the TextView's listener?

Comment: Hmm come to think of it that may be it. perhaps my autoCompleteTextView is just calling it's filter provider in the default way and not accessing my onTextChangeed. So i changed it from an autoCompleteTextView to a EditText and i'm trying to do search.addTextChangedListener() but if i am implementing TextWatcher as part of my class what do i put inside the ()?

Comment: I have no experience with TextWatcher. If this is a dead end let me know and ill remove my answer

Comment: Ignore my last comment, changed my class so that it did not implement TextWatcher and just added my listener into the class. It is working beautifully now thanks so much for the help! I'd like to post my working example just in case anyone else has this problem. What is the best way to do that editing your post?

Comment: If my answer is related to your solution, you can edit it. If it's not, you can just post your own answer :-)